# How to get current page's Type and refresh it in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8.1 app I want to get the current page type and If It matches my check to refresh that page. How to do it? This doesn't work:

```C#
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
var pageType = (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content.GetType();
```

About the refreshing:

If you only want to refresh the page if it's of a specific type (let's call it `MyPage`), you can do something like this:

```
var page = (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content as MyPage;
if (page != null) {
    page.Refresh(); //This is a method that you implement in the page, that refreshes it
}
```

If there are several types of pages that you would like to refresh, make an interface with one method called Refresh and use `as IMyInterface` instead of `as MyPage` in the above example.

Now, if you really want to refresh by navigation (which does not seem like the best idea), you can do something like:

```
var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage));
frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(frame.BackStack.Count - 1); //Or RemoveAt(0), haven't tested it
```

But this approach will not work in some cases.

Comment: It works, but how to refresh that page then (only refresh, not to add another one in the backstack)

Comment: @V.G. I modified the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks yasen, more than a year later you saved my day.
Handnligh WPF/XAML object navigation it's something i have always trouble.